# Visible Blocks in Flow Document Reader

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

I currently have a FlowDocumentReader placed and am trying to determine how to tell what blocks are visible.

Specifically I have a document outline on the side of the screen and I am trying to highlight to sections which are on screen. I have tried using the

```
Block.ContentStart
Block.ContentEnd
```

commands, which do seem to be giving me good TextPointer values but I am not sure what to do with these. I know you can call BringIntoView() on a Block and it will move the document to make it visible. Is there a similar method which I do not see just to tell if a block is visible? Or, on a FlowDocumentReader is there a method to get the current position in the document that I do not see?

Thank you!